# ASN.1 Type References in Value Assignments

Tags: asn.1

In ASN.1, Value Assignment syntax requires an identifier, a Type Reference, and a Value. Such as:

```
age INTEGER ::= 45
```

or

```
name UTF8String ::= "bob"
```

Generally, a user-defined type would be a more complex type, such as a SEQUENCE or a type with constraints.  Suppose we have a SEQUENCE type like this:

```
MySequence ::= SEQUENCE {
  age INTEGER,
  name UTF8String
}
```

I could then create a Value Assignment like:

```
seq MySequence ::= { 50, "bob" }
```

But suppose `MySequence` was never defined.  Is it legal to define types on the fly when creating a Value Assignment?  For example, could I say:

```
seq SEQUENCE {  age INTEGER, name UTF8String } ::= { 50, "bob" }
```

I realize this syntax is ugly, but I'm simply asking if this ALLOWED by the ASN.1 standard.

Or what about creating a Sub Type on the fly in a Value Assignment?  Is it valid ASN.1 syntax to say:

```
int INTEGER (0..10) ::= 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is valid ASN.1, but has limited usefulness when passed to an ASN.1 Tool.  Feel free to try this in the free online compiler at http://asn1-playground.oss.com.